# Send Locally Stored Image to Server Via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, cordova

I have looked high and low for a straight forward answer to this question.

I have an image loaded locally in a phone gap application in the following directory:

```
/image/test.png
```

I want to send this image to the server as part of a multi-part form using form data.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
```

I then append my JSON

```
formdata.append("json", JSON.stringify(request));
```

I then want to append the image and I tried using the following

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = './image/test.png';

formdata.append("file", img.src );

$.ajax(
{
  url : "http://myserver:8080/myservlet",
  type : "POST",
  data : formdata,
  processData : false,
  contentType : false,
  dataType : "json",
  success : function(response)
  {
    console.log("success response:"+JSON.stringify(response));
  },
  error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
  {
    var msg = "Error Sending File. Status: "+textStatus+" Error:"+errorThrown;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, "Error", "OK");
  }
});
```

This if course is not working for me - what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this [plugin](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64) to get base64 encoding of your local image then send it to server using ajax:

```
window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile(filePath, function(base64){
        console.log('file base64 encoding: ' + base64);
        //write down ajax code to send base64 string
    });
```

Comment: Then you have to get all base64 for all files using javascript async or promises then send the whole array to server

Comment: Hello Hazem. The problem I see is that when the function(base64) is called, I cannot know which file has been encoded (filePath is not available I think) so I cannot set it to a <span id='filePath'> for example. Hopefully, I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On phonegap you can use the FileTransfer plugin. On post PhoneGap 3 you have to include the plugin in your config.xml

```
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
```

Then to upload to the server do something like this:

```
  var imageUploadSuccess = function (data) {
        alert("Cool");
  }
  var imageUploadFail = function (error) {
    alert("fail");
  }

  var params = new Object();
  params.yourHttpParam = "My Param Value";
  var url ="http://myserver.com/photo/upload";

  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileName = "/image/test.png";
  options.mimeType = "image/png";
  options.fileKey = "file";
  options.params = params;
  options.chunkedMode = false;
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.upload("/image/test.png", url, imageUploadSuccess, imageUploadFail, options, true);
```

Comment: Note if you're uploading from the camera /  imageURI, use : `imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)` to get the filename.

Comment: thanks let me check out sending the other items as parameters, I assume this uses a POST and form data type transfer behind the scenes.

Comment: It is a post and the file will be a Miltipart file however you implement that on the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`FileTransfer`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) API, note that there are some problems with it at the time of writing ([however they are being addressed.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2293)).

See the documentation here for details. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Here's a quick example:

```
var fileURI = // imageURI returned by the CameraAPI.

var success = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var fail = function (error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/plain";

// The following options are to attempt circumvention of the
// FileTransfer.upload issues in the linked Cordova thread.
// Note that they are reportedly, not always effective.
options.headers={Connection: "close"};
options.chunkedMode = false;

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), success, fail, options);
```

You will need to enable the file and file-transfer plugins in your Android Manifest.

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
```

**A quick note about the known problems...** uploading will fail on every other subsequent upload (ie. success, fail, success, fail, etc...) - Note that this problem has affected iOS and Android (I can't speak for BB or other platforms.) AFAIK, Android is still affected, but I recommend you [read the thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2293) and keep an eye on it.

There are recommended solutions/workarounds, however they are also reported to fail (ie. turn off chunked mode and attempting to force close the connection.)

Until there is a reliable fix, it is better to simply keep an attempted connection counter, and handle the even numbered fails as cause to immediately re-try. (nasty, but necessary.)

Comment: I have no problems on android uploading an image with additional post data. I'm using the upload options like stated in my answer. I have no upload errors at all...

Comment: As I say, refer to the thread linked above. It certainly doesn't appear to affect every device, but as you'll read, it's widely reported.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans for some instances, close / chunked fixes the issue, but in others, not. - fyi, I'll add `Connection: close` to my example.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to upload an image (=file) but in fact you are posting a string returned by `img.src`. If you like to post your image you'll need to convert it to a string that can be posted. you can do this by loading your image into a canvas element and get call [toDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/HTMLCanvasElement). However when using phonegap, I recommend uploading the file through a filetransfer and add your additional post data to it...

```
function uploadPhoto(imageUrlToUpload) {
    //alert('upload: '+imageUriToUpload);
    var url=encodeURI(youruploadurl);
    var params = new Object();
    params.your_param_name = "something";  //add your additional post parameters here
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.headers={Connection: "close"};
    options.fileKey = "file"; //depends on the api
    options.fileName = imageUriToUpload.substr(imageUriToUpload.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false; //this is important to send both data and files
    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    //what to do during the file transfer? lets show some percentage...
    var status=$('yourselectorhere');//element in the dom that gets updated during the onprogress
    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        var perc;

        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {


                perc = Math.ceil(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);

                status.html(perc+'%'+ '('+progressEvent.total+')');

        }else{alert('not computable');}
    };

    ft.upload(imageUrlToUpload, url, success, fail, options);
}

function success(r) {
    alert("Upload success: Code = " + r.responseCode);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
}
```

Comment: In passing in additional parameters - I am trying to find a parallel to form data so I assume I have a name and a value parameters.  So is formdata.append("name", "value" equal to params.name = "value"?  And is this basically a multi/part POST?